# Can't have more than 1 [Radio Buttons (2 Buttons)] Dialog in Web Setup Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project, web-setup-project

I've added a dialog to my Web Setup Project allowing the user to choose between two options. I did this by right clicking on the project and choosing View -> User Interface.
I then Right clicked Start -> Add Dialog and chose Radio Buttons (2 Buttons).

If I try to add another this way, the Radio Buttons (2 Buttons) option is gone. I'm assuming this is because I already have one, that's so ridiculous I don't want it to be true.

How can I add a second dialog with 2 radio buttons?